# calling HTTP requests in angularjs in batched form?

Tags: ajax, http, angularjs

I have two for loops and an HTTP call inside them.

```
for(i=0;i<m;i++) {
  for(j=0;j<n;j++) {
    $http call that uses i and j as GET parameters
    .success(//something)
    .error(//something more)
  }
}
```

The problem with this is it makes around 200-250 AJAX calls based on values of m and n. This is causing problem of browser crash when tried to access from mobile.
I would like to know if there is a way to call HTTP requests in batched form (n requests at a time) and once these calls are finished, move to next batch and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I did it is as follows (this will help when one wants to call HTTP requests in a batch of `n requests at a time` )

```
call batchedHTTP(with i=0);

batchedHTTP = function() {
  /* check for terminating condition (in this case, i=m) */
  for(j=0;j<n;j++) {
    var promise = $http call with i and j GET parameters
    .success(// do something)
    .error(// do something else)

    promisesArray.push(promise);
  }
  $q.all(promisesArray).then(function() {
    call batchedHTTP(with i=i+1)
  });
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You could always use a proper HTTP batch module like this [angular-http-batcher](https://github.com/jonsamwell/angular-http-batcher) - which will take all of the requests and turn them into a single HTTP POST request before sending it to the server.  Therefore it reduces 250 calls into 1!  The module is here https://github.com/jonsamwell/angular-http-batcher and a detailed explanation of it is here http://jonsamwell.com/batching-http-requests-in-angular/

Comment: This is the correct answer when asking to do batch requests. The other answers just limits the concurrent requests to a given number.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, use the async library found here: https://github.com/caolan/async

First, use the loop to create your tasks:

```
var tasks = []; //array to hold the tasks
for(i=0;i<m;i++) {
  for(j=0;j<n;j++) {
    //we add a function to the array of "tasks" 
    //Async will pass that function a standard callback(error, data)
    tasks.push(function(cb){
       //because of the way closures work, you may not be able to rely on i and j here
       //if i/j don't work here, create another closure and store them as params
       $http call that uses i and j as GET parameters
       .success(function(data){cb(null, data);})
       .error(function(err){cb(err);});
    });
  }
}
```

Now that you've got an array full of callback-ready functions that can be executed, you must use async to execute them, async has a great feature to "limit" the number of simultaneous requests and therefore "batch".

```
async.parallelLimit(tasks, 10, function(error, results){
    //results is an array with each tasks results.
    //Don't forget to use $scope.$apply or $timeout to trigger a digest
});
```

In the above example you will run 10 tasks at a time in parallel.

Async has a ton of other amazing options as well, you can run things in series, parlallel, map arrays, etc.It's worth noting that you might be able to achieve greater efficiency by using a single function and the "eachLimit" function of async.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jonathan. I tried using $q.all for all n requests from inner for loop and it's working as expected. But the solution you provided is much more flexible, as it allows one to specify the number of http requests fired simultaneously, without bothering about the values of m and n.